# How to use variables inside view without assigning them php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view

I have a question. Ive made some mvc'ish structure for my website.
I want to be able to use my variables inside my view without assigning them.

Let me explain by an example, here's a small part of my controller :

```
class members extends controller{

public function _construct()
{
    parent::__construct();        

}
public function index()
{
    $test = 'test variable';
    $data['test2'] = 'test variable 2';

    view::setTemplate('header');
    view::setTemplate('homepage', $data);
    view::setTemplate('footer');
}
}
```

in the setTemplate() function of my view class, I use `extract($data)` and then I include the view file. This way I can echo $test2 and get 'test variable 2' as output, as expected.

However, is there a way to make the view 'remember' the first $test variable without having to add it to the setTemplate function ?

Comment: I think the question to ask here is: why? Remembering that writing explicit, self-documenting code is of a top priority for maintainability.

Comment: `$this->test = 'test variable';` so it becomes an attribute of the object.

Comment: `extract()` is one of the worst PHP functions ever. Thanks for making the lives of future devs who need to debug your code hell.

Comment: Why is extract so bad?

Comment: Because it makes debugging a nightmare - variables should be declared and disclosed to the script. Extract is like - "hey, TRUST ME, there are some incoming vars.... the ones referenced below may or may not have been defined in the array of crap I'm extracting, but...that's your problem not mine"

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: THIS CODE HAS NOT BEEN TESTED**

You can use variable variables to define the variables within the setTemplate method and include the view directly from there.

```
<?php
function setTemplate($view, $data) {
  if(is_array($data)){
    foreach($data as $var => $val){
      $$var = $val;
    }
  }
  include('views/'.$view.'.php');
}
?>
```